# XPathApply- how to get results from TreeParse

Tags: r, xml

I'm having difficulty getting the tags to parse information via XPathApply. The desired information on the website is an "input" cell, and I don't know how to retrieve it. E.g. With the following info, I could extract it as such:

```
<div><span>3.2</span></div>
<div><span>6.9</span></div>
<div><span>2.5</span></div>

as.numeric(unlist(xpathApply(*HTMLText*, '//span', xmlValue))
```

However, I have have lines that look like:

```
<div class="editable-cell"><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="32"></div>
<div class="editable-cell"><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="33"></div>
<div class="editable-cell"><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="20"></div>
```

And I have no clue which sort of tag to use in order to retrieve the value inside `value = "*"`. I tried '//value', '//div', etc. and it doesn't work for me.

I apologize in advance for not really creating reproducible code, but I figure it would be easy enough to identify the tag needed to get the values. Also, is there any resource out there to get better at identifying which tags I need?

Thanks

Comment: use `xmlAttrs`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `r`, but the XPath to get attribute `value` from element `input` would be: `//input/@value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XML::xmlAttrs` to retrieve attributes

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse('<div class="editable-cell"><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="32"></div>
<div class="editable-cell"><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="33"></div>
<div class="editable-cell"><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="20"></div>')

unlist(lapply(xpathApply(doc, '//input', xmlAttrs), '[[', "value"))

#or
xpathSApply(doc, '//input', function(x) xmlAttrs(x)[["value"]])

#or as suggested by @har07
xpathSApply(doc, '//input/@value', I)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I looked all over the documentations, and I couldn't find what the `I` does at the end of your last example, could you explain? I also can never understand what the `'[['` is in `lapply`s

Comment: Check out ?I . It returns itself

Comment: ?’[[‘ accesses a list

Comment: Wow, sounds like I need to stop relying on `dplyr` and learn more about base functions. Thanks again for the help